# freemarker map with non string keys

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm trying to process `Map<com.taskadapter.redmineapi.bean.Version, Map<com.taskadapter.redmineapi.bean.User, List<com.taskadapter.redmineapi.bean.Issue>>>` using Freemarker.

I read the doc about issue when using `Map` with non `String` keys: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys

And that is my piece of code

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_22);
configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(Main.class.getClass(), "/");
configuration.setAPIBuiltinEnabled(true);
Template template = configuration.getTemplate("myTemplate.ftl");

Map<String, Object> templateData = new HashMap<>();
templateData.put("myMap", myMap);

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
template.process(templateData, outputStreamWriter);
```

and my template

```
<#list myMap?keys as key>
        <h2>${key}</h2>
        <#list myMap?api.get(key)?keys as key2>
            ${key2}
        </#list>
</#list>
```

But I have the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> myMap?api.get  [in template "template.ftl" at line 196, column 40]
```

Any idea?

---

Update: the map is type of

`Map<com.taskadapter.redmineapi.bean.Version, Map<com.taskadapter.redmineapi.bean.User, List<com.taskadapter.redmineapi.bean.Issue>>>`

The map is created from `com.google.common.collect.Table<Version, User, List<Issue>>` using method `rowMap()`

---

Possible solution: if I use `<#list myMap?values[key_index]?keys as key2>` it works.

Comment: Works for me... I think we should see what exactly `myMap` is. There are a couple of oversights BTW, none of them related to the question: `Main.class.getClass()` meant to be `Main.class`, and you are missing yet another `?keys` after the 2nd `#list`'s first parameter.

Comment: I just updated my question. Yeah I was missing `?keys` just added but nothing better. `Main.class` is just the class where I launch my code, if just for `classloader`

Comment: With `Table` and `rowMap()` it still works form me. There must be some kind of oversight there. Like, maybe `myMap` is not the result of `rowMap()` but the `Table` itself. (As of the `Main.class.getClass()`, what I'm saying is that you don't need the `.getClass()` at the end of it.)

Comment: I will post a full code on github asap